# How to disable URL encoding in Indy's TIdHTTP.Get()?

Tags: delphi, indy

I have D2010 and the latest Indy Tiburon from Atozed's SVN. I use Get() function in TIdHTTP and I know that Indy URL-encodes bad characters in URL. I want TIdHTTP to not do that so my question is **how can I disable auto encoding URL in TIdHTTP.Get()**?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the LATEST revision of Indy? The Tiburon branch does not exist anymore, it was merged into the Trunk awhile ago.  As for the URL encoding, what do you consider to be "bad characters"?  Indy does not encode the URL you try to talk to, it only encodes the DATA that you try to post to that URL.  Can you provide more details about the actual situation you are having problems with?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm not really sure if it's Tiburion. What I'm sure is that I'm using the latest version of Indy since I see that it's updated something about weekly.

By "bad characters" I mean non-ASCII chars like in this case Polish letters like ę, ó, ą, ś, ł, ż, ź, ć, ń. I want to make a GET request with that characters. Everything worked fine in version of Indy that was included with D2010. Upgrading to SVN version made problems - rubbish results on a search page of some website.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure hoForceEncodeParams is not turned on in `TIdHttp.Options`.

Comment: As long as I remember [hoForceEncodeParams] is used in TIdHTTP.Post, which I'm not using ;)